# how can i export 300million records from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, export, mongoexport

I have 300million records in my mongodb,I want to export all records from it ,but

i can only export about 30million data and got no error messager! I don't kown

whether it is the limit of mongoexport  or something wrong with my export.Does

anyone got thie problem? Any help will be appreciated.My export is as follows:

```
/home/mongodb/bin/mongoexport -h 10.141.209.2 -p 27018 -d test -c microblogs --fields 'user_id,created_at,reposts_count,comments_count,source,text'  --skip 36176225    --type=csv -o  microblogs_36176225.csv
```

The results lookes like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         60 Sep 29 21:39 microblogs_36176225.csv
```

Comment: What does the `--skip 36176225` do?

Comment: @dummy Nice spot. It skips about 36M records...

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a limit, but I would try first exporting to json to see if you have the same issue if you do.
You could try doing splicing the exports, since it "failed" at around 30 million do this

```
mongoexport --skip 0 --limit 30000000 -- sort{_id:1} --db microblogs
mongoexport --skip 30000000 --limit 30000000 -- sort{_id:1} --db microblogs
util you reach your 300 million
```

a loop in your language of choice could take care of this for you easily so that your not manually typing this up.

Hope this helps.